# Select tables in database and group them by partial name

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a database that gets new tables automatically added to it via create table if not exists statements.

The table names are in the following format:

somenamebasedondatasource_YEAR_period_X

Where X is a financial period of the business year, being a number 1-13.

Is there a query I can run against the schema table to get all the tables in the database then group them by the year contained in the name of the table.

So if my current tables list looks like this:

```
somenamebasedondatasource_2018_period_1
somenamebasedondatasource_2018_period_2
somenamebasedondatasource_2018_period_3
somenamebasedondatasource_2018_period_4
somenamebasedondatasource_2018_period_5
somenamebasedondatasource_2018_period_6
somenamebasedondatasource_2018_period_7
somenamebasedondatasource_2019_period_8
somenamebasedondatasource_2019_period_9
somenamebasedondatasource_2019_period_10
somenamebasedondatasource_2019_period_11
somenamebasedondatasource_2019_period_12
somenamebasedondatasource_2019_period_13
somenamebasedondatasource_2018_period_1
somenamebasedondatasource_2019_period_2
somenamebasedondatasource_2019_period_3
somenamebasedondatasource_2019_period_4
somenamebasedondatasource_2019_period_5
somenamebasedondatasource_2019_period_6
somenamebasedondatasource_2019_period_7
someothernamedatasourcesource_2018_period_1
someothernamedatasourcesource_2018_period_2
someothernamedatasourcesource_2018_period_3
someothernamedatasourcesource_2018_period_4
someothernamedatasourcesource_2018_period_5
someothernamedatasourcesource_2018_period_6
someothernamedatasourcesource_2018_period_7
someothernamedatasourcesource_2019_period_8
someothernamedatasourcesource_2019_period_9
someothernamedatasourcesource_2019_period_10
someothernamedatasourcesource_2019_period_11
someothernamedatasourcesource_2019_period_12
someothernamedatasourcesource_2019_period_13
someothernamedatasourcesource_2018_period_1
someothernamedatasourcesource_2019_period_2
someothernamedatasourcesource_2019_period_3
someothernamedatasourcesource_2019_period_4
someothernamedatasourcesource_2019_period_5
someothernamedatasourcesource_2019_period_6
someothernamedatasourcesource_2019_period_7
```

I would like an output that lists:

```
2018
2019
```

Then when the list of tables gets bigger into 2020 and beyond, it lists any years for those tables too like

```
2018
2019
2020
```

```sql
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = database_name
/*not sure what else goes here.
```

After that I also want to do the same thing again for the period_X but only for a certain year. (so after a user selects the year from the first query, I want to show them the periods for that year from the result of the second query.)

PS: I can change the naming convention for the tables if that makes this easier, it's all just test data at this point. Each table does contain the year and period in a column in each of it's rows, I was only splitting them up to try to avoid big long select queries when grabbing the data for later use. (the tables contain a row for each minute of the day during office hours, so will end up fairly large and huge if multiple periods and years are put together.)

Comment: You have encountered one of many reasons not to build a bunch of identical tables.

Comment: @RickJames I explained why I chose to do it that way at the bottom of my question. Can you suggest a better method to avoid very large tables and still achieve something like this?

Comment: Show us the queries that benefit from your multi-table approach.  I can probably show you how they can be made just as efficient with a single, huge, table.

Comment: @RickJames. The only thing I'm doing with the data is querying it just like Gordon has showed me how in the answer below to find the table the user wants, then just selecting all the contents with a basic ```SELECT * WHERE date = somedate``` statement. Perhaps occasionally exporting with phpmyadmin if I were to ever need an entire table for something.

I'm only trying to avoid large tables because it's running a virtual machine with 4GB of RAM and access to 2 Xenon cores hosted on a remote IBM machine. I have no specific reason other than having limited experiance of know what is too much.

Comment: If you have `INDEX(date)`, it won't need to look through the entire table.  And 4GB will be plenty big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string operations:

```
SELECT DISTINCT substring_index(substring_index(TABLE_NAME, '_', 2), '_', -1)
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = database_name
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. That looks like it's the feature I need to use for this, but you seem to have a typo in your example. For anyone else reading, it's `SELECT DISTINCT substring_index(substring_index( TABLE_NAME, '_', 2), '_', -1)
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = database_name`
Note the change of a comma for a open rounded bracket.